# Opera doesn't recognize links — images and css3 columns

Tags: image, css, opera, anchor

Opera is the only browser I've tested that doesn't recognize the links on my home page. I can click on a few of the images and go to the linked page, but most don't do anything when I click. The cursor even remains an arrow. Works in every other browser.

http://test.davewhitley.com/not-wp/mobile_test/

They are images wrapped in anchor tags and the grid is created with css columns.

Any ideas?

**Update**:
The same links that are not clickable also aren't inspect-able in opera's web inspector.

**Update**:
Please note that some of the images ***are*** click-able on the left hand side. Which images are click-able varies with the browser width. If you view the website > 1300px browser width then most of the images are not click-able on the right side.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Could you report a bug on https://bugs.opera.com/wizard/ and tell me what bug ID you get?

Comment: @c69 Weird. I have the same version and it doesn't work for me. The images on the left side are click-able but the right ones are not. Also, it depends on your browser width. View it > 1300px width.

Comment: @hallvors I submitted the bug and this is the confirmation message I received. http://cl.ly/1A0E1x2s1k2Z2u0k2W2a Not sure if that email they gave me is the ID. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: @hallvors The ID is DSK-359458

Comment: thanks, I'll try to get some analysis done here and will get back to you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a known bug in Opera 11.6x which is fixed in the most recent previews of Opera 12. I don't know of any workaround right now, but given that a fix is coming in the not too distant future I would simply wait for it.